# Laserscan to PointCloud

Tags: rviz, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello folks

I need to convert the Laserscanner data from my Hokuyo Laser Range Finder into a PointCloud.
I know there is a package called laser_assembler which should do this.
But i can't manage to make it working. There's a launch file in the test directory, but this one didnt what i expected.
What I need is a launch file, which converts the laserscanners topic /scan to a pointcloud topic /scan_pointcloud for example, so I can visualize it in Rviz as a first step.

I will appreciate any kind of help!
Regards,

Timo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172756/laserscan-to-pointcloud/) by [cobhc999](https://answers.ros.org/users/14666/cobhc999/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-06-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-04**:
Do you need a single scan as points or multiple merged ones? The latter is what laser_assembler does. Converting a single scan is rather simple. For visualization in rviz, just use a LaserScan display.

**Comment by [cobhc999](https://answers.ros.org/users/14666/cobhc999/) on 2014-06-04**:
I don't need merged ones. Just the actual ones, but not as polar coordinates. I need them as Cartesian coordinates. I know, I can visualize just the laserscan topic in Rviz. But I need them as a pointcloud. In a later approach I have to detect circles in the pointcloud, thats why I need Cartesian coordinates.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-04**:
In that case I'd suggest to just to that manually in the code, unless that is something that you cannot change and needs pointcloud input. Then you could just write a simple node that does the conversion.

**Comment by [cobhc999](https://answers.ros.org/users/14666/cobhc999/) on 2014-06-06**:
Ok, I managed to run the assembler and the periodic snapshotter. But it only gets new points after about 4sec. But I cant find the variable to change, which makes the snapshotter publish the points more often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A simple converter node is available via the [hector_laserscan_to_pointcloud](https://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/hector_sandbox/hector_laserscan_to_pointcloud/src/laserscan_to_pointcloud_node.cpp) package. It should be pretty straightforward to use and do what you request.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2014-10-22**:
Hi Stefan
I cant find this package on http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php, how can I incorporate this package to my hydro ros?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-05-08**:
The laser_geometry package has the core functions for doing this: http://wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have been playing around with the laser_assembler package and managed to make it work for assembling several laser scans into a single point cloud, and publish that point cloud on a topic.

What I have done is the following:

1. I create a package that will
   handle all the logic
2. On the
   launch file of that package, I
   launch the laser_assembler properly
   configured and my own node
3. My
   node subscribes to the service of
   the laser_assembler that provides
   point clouds
4. Then it calls the
   service, gets the response, and then
   publishes on a topic as a single
   PointCloud2 message

How to do it ===========

Using Python to do the conversion simplifies a lot. Let's see how to do that using the laser_geometry package.

First, you need to launch the laser_geometry package from a launch file, properly configured. Here a suggested launch file:

```
<launch>
<node type="laser_scan_assembler" pkg="laser_assembler"
    name="my_assembler">
<remap from="scan" to="laser_scan"/>
<param name="max_scans" type="int" value="400" />
<param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="my_robot_link_base" />
 </node>
  <node type ="laser2pc.py" pkg="laser_to_pcl" name="laser2pc"/>
</launch>
```

That file launches the laser_geometry package indicating that the frame from which the transform will be done is the my_robot_link_base (that is whatever tf link of your robot you want the point cloud to be refered from). Another parameter is the max_scans which indicates the max number of last scans that will be take into account for the computation of the point cloud ( this is useful in case your laser is rotating, so you can generate a full 3D cloud).

The launch file above also launches a second node that is the one you have to create to get the data and publish it into your selected topic. What should be the code of such a node? Check the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy 
from laser_assembler.srv import AssembleScans2
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2

rospy.init_node("assemble_scans_to_cloud")
rospy.wait_for_service("assemble_scans2")
assemble_scans = rospy.ServiceProxy('assemble_scans2', AssembleScans2)
pub = rospy.Publisher ("/laser_pointcloud", PointCloud2, queue_size=1)

r = rospy.Rate (1)

while (True):
    try:
        resp = assemble_scans(rospy.Time(0,0), rospy.get_rostime())
        print "Got cloud with %u points" % len(resp.cloud.data)
        pub.publish (resp.cloud)

    except rospy.ServiceException, e:
        print "Service call failed: %s"%e

    r.sleep()
```

The code shows how to subscribe to the assemble_scans2 service. That is the one that will provide the point cloud on its answer. The code also shows that the point cloud will be published on a topic of type PoinCloud2. basically, the while loop what it does is, first, call to the service, then publish the answer of the service into a topic.

I have created a video describing step by step and code solution. In case you are interested, [you can find it here](http://www.theconstructsim.com/merge-laser-scans-single-pointcloud/)

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-31**:
This answer would be much more useful if you provided a minimal working example of your launch files/code.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2017-10-09**:
Modified as suggested